# A InspectionFormProvider was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter

When I try to click the button using Provider this error appears:
**A InspectionFormProvider was used after being disposed.**
Once you have called dispose() on a InspectionFormProvider, it can no longer be used. What caused this error to appear?

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) {
    return inspectionFormProvider;
  },
  Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(...),
            label: Text(...),
            onPressed: () {
              inspectionFormProvider.insertItem();
            },
          ),
      ),
      Consumer<InspectionFormProvider>(
        builder: (context, InspectionFormProvider, _) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: inspectionFormList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InspectionFormCard(...);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```